# ¿Cómo es la forma en que el autofill del navegador le pasa el valor al input?

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy estudiando Javascript e hice un pequeño login, y lo que pasa es que cuando guardo mis credenciales en el navegador, al recargar mi login el navegador llena los input con dichas credenciales, y mi duda es ¿donde se almacena esos valores?, ya que al checar la propiedad value de mi input sale vacía y las letras de mi input se ven pequeñas y al dar un click en cualquier parte del formulario ya se ponen del tamaño normal que tienen asignado.

Si alguien me puede pasar alguna información se los agradecería mucho, ya que he estado investigando y no he podido llegar a una respuesta

Comment: Por seguridad, no se permite el acceso con JavaScript del autocompletado de credenciales, esta fuera del alcance del programador pero puedes encontrarlas en las opciones de configuración del navegador. En cuanto a lo de las letras no se porque será, puedes pasar el código del login? html css y js

Comment: Ok Gracias, lo de las letras pequeñas investigue y es como algo del navegador que solo las pone como "encima" de los input pero como tal no están dentro de él. Quizá existe una propiedad en el input para que esos valores estén dentro de el